# Extract image data when pulling in RSS feeds using PHP

Tags: php, rss

The script I am using to pull in the feed titles is:

```
<?php  

function getFeed($feed_url) {  

$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);  
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);  

echo "<ul>";  

foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {  
    echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a>    </li>";
    $i++;
    if($i==5) break;        
}  
echo "</ul>";  
}  
?>
```

I would like to pull in the images for each title/article and place them next to the title.

The float part is easy. I'm having trouble getting the actual image in. I've tried that mark like this: `<img src="$entry->image" />`, but it didn't work.

How would I go about this please?

Comment: an <img> with float: left? or what do you exactly want?

Comment: so... `echo "<img src="$entry->whatever" />"`?

Comment: Yeah an image with float eft, but the float part is easy - I'm having trouble getting the actual image in. I've tried that mark like this: <img src="$entry->image" /> it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As the answer to random's suggestion:

- I'm using $item['description'] to represent the description string.
- Then match for img tag
- Output image tag
- Then remove the image tag from the original $content and output that, you're left with just the description text

  ```
  <?php 
      $content = $item['description'];
      preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $content, $matches);
      echo $matches[0];
      echo str_replace($matches[0],"",$content);
  ?>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

When displaying the feed contents, variables such as `$entry->link` and `$entry->title` work because they are valid, present and [**required** elements in a standard RSS feed item](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt).

To call `$entry->image` would require the source RSS to use and populate that **optional** element.

Some feeds may include that data, but most will not.

Alternatively, you can write your own function or method to scan the contents of the `description` element and find any suitable image to include as you need.